# C# Adding objects to listBox and then changing their parameters

Tags: c#, listbox, addition

How can I add new object to listBox and then change their parameters?

I have a class:

```
public class Triangle
{
    public Triangle(double a, double b, double c): base(a, b, c)
    { }
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double a = 3;
    double b = 4;
    double c = 5;

    Triangle t = new Triangle(a, b, c);
    listBox1.Items.Add("Triangle");
}
```

How can I change length of the sides of this `Triangle` (new values will be from `Textbox`) and update this class object?

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to expose the properties on your Triangle class:

```
public class Triangle
{

    public double SideA { get; set; }
    public double SideB { get; set; }
    public double SideC { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Triangle(double a, double b, double c, string n)
    {
        SideA = a;
        SideB = b;
        SideC = c;
        Name = n;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Note that I have added a Name property that will get displayed by default (because of the ToString() override) in your ListBox.

Then, add your Triangles to the ListBox:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new Triangle(1, 2, 3, "One"));
listBox1.Items.Add(new Triangle(1, 2, 3, "Two"));
listBox1.Items.Add(new Triangle(1, 2, 3, "Three"));
```

And finally, is some other part of your code you will have to first obtain a reference to a Triangle object from the ListBox:

```
Triangle t = listBox1.SelectedItem as Triangle;
if (t != null)
    t.SideA = 10;
```

Please note that I'm assuming you want to edit the currently selected Triangle.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that the numer of elements (triangles) in listBox is limitless, so I can't using the name string. It should be dynamic adding after click a button, but after the select element in listbox you can change for example lenght of the sides